# ffmpeg add music to video that might also have audio (or might not), without loosing the existing audio

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I am working on a script that should allow me to add an audio to a video, that video might or might not have an audio stream, when it does have, I can just use `filter_complex` and `amix` to combine the 2 audios and -map it to the output.

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio_to_add.mp4 -filter_complex "[0][1]amix=inputs=2[newAudio]" -map 0:v -map [newAudio]:a output.mp4
```

My issue is that when the video does not have an audio stream, the `amix` filter throws an error

```
Stream specifier '' in filtergraph description [0][1]amix=inputs=2[newAudio] matches no streams
```

Comment: What is the script language?

Comment: "when it does have, i can just use filter_complex and amix to combine the 2 audios and -map it to the output," why not add an additional audio track? That's the usual way to deal e.g. with videos and multiple language audio.

Comment: cause i want to keep both audios

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't use `amix` filter when your video doesn't have any audio,
try using this command for your case :

```
amovie=audio_to_add.mp4:loop=0,asetpts=N/SR/TB,volume=1.0[a]
```

**Update**

> Refer this link to check if your video have any audio or not

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46483591/10752962

```
if (isVideoMuted) {
        if (isLongVideo) {
            if (isLoop) {
                commandList.add("amovie=" + mAudioFileName + ":loop=0,asetpts=N/SR/TB,volume=" + addedVolume + "[a]");
            }
        } else {
            commandList.add("amovie=" + mAudioFileName + ":loop=0,asetpts=N/SR/TB,volume=" + addedVolume + "[a]");
        }
    } else {
        if (isLongVideo) {
            if (!isLoop) {
                commandList.add("[0:a]volume=" + originalVolume + "[a0];[1:a]volume=" + addedVolume + "[a1];[a0][a1]amix=inputs=2[a]");
            } else {
                commandList.add("amovie=" + mAudioFileName + ":loop=0,asetpts=N/SR/TB,volume=" + addedVolume + "[a1];[0:a]volume=" + originalVolume + "[a0],[a0][a1]amix=inputs=2[a]");
            }
        } else {
            commandList.add("[0:a]volume=" + originalVolume + "[a0];[1:a]volume=" + addedVolume + "[a1];[a0][a1]amix=inputs=2[a]");
        }
    }
```

Here, `isLongVideo` is used for if video is longer than audio and `isLoop` is used if you want to set looping for audio if video is longer(this use case depends on you).

I have also added `-shortest` command like this :

```
    if (!isLongVideo) {
        commandList.add("-shortest");
    } else {
        if (isLoop) {
            commandList.add("-shortest");
        }
    }
```

Have a look at this code and check which part is useful for you and how to implement according to your need..

Comment: this is my current cmd 
`ffmpeg -i might_have_audio.mp4 -i additional_music.mp3 -filter_complex "[0][1]amix=inputs=2[combinedaudio]" -map 0:v -map [combinedaudio]:a output.mp4`
it works well when the original video has audio, but throws an error when the original video does not have, where should i put your suggestion to have the cmd work for any video (with or without audio)?

Comment: So in short, I will first have to check if the input video has an audio stream, and based on that condition choose what ffmpeg cmd to run, if it has audio i will combine it with my additional audio (with the amix filter) and then map the new audio stream to the output video, an if it does not have an audio stream i will simply map the audio i want to add to the output stream 

i was trying to do it with a single cmd, but i assume it not possible

Comment: Yes, you got it right and i don't know if you can use single command for this or not,but i'm also using multiple commands.So,for right now use this and bestOfLuck